# Javascript calendar compatibility on iPad or iPhone?

Tags: javascript, php, ios

I am having a problem regarding with viewing my custom calendar display on ipad or iphone. It work perfectly on desktop, iMac and android device but not ipad or iphone which is ios based.

The problem is the `<tr></tr>` seems not working as the calendar is viewing with a straight line rather than making a new line after reaching the end of the week. I'm thinking that the it might be the javascript compatibility issue between the two platform.
Below is the script to generate the calendar.

```
<script>
function calendar(month) {

var padding = "";
var totalFeb = "";
var i = 1;
var testing = "";

var current = new Date();
var cmonth = current.getMonth();
var day = current.getDate();
<?php if (isset($_GET['year']))
{
$year = $_GET['year'];
?>
var year = <?php echo $year ?>;
<?php
}
else
{
 ?>
var year = current.getFullYear();
<?php } 
?>
var tempMonth = month + 1;
var prevMonth = month - 1;


if (month == 1) {
    if ((year % 100 !== 0) && (year % 4 === 0) || (year % 400 === 0)) {
        totalFeb = 29;
    } else {
        totalFeb = 28;
    }
}

var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var dayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var totalDays = ["31", "" + totalFeb + "", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31"];

var tempDate = new Date(tempMonth + ' 1 ,' + year);
var tempweekday = tempDate.getDay();
var tempweekday2 = tempweekday;
var dayAmount = totalDays[month];

while (tempweekday > 0) {

    padding += "<td class='premonth' bgcolor='#E0E0DF'></td>";
    //preAmount++;
    tempweekday--;

    }
while (i <= dayAmount) {

var paramM = <?php echo $a; ?>;
var paramY = <?php echo $yearcalendar; ?>;
var totalParam = ""+paramY+"-"+paramM+"-"+i+"";

    if (tempweekday2 > 6) {
        tempweekday2 = 0;
        padding += "</tr><tr>";
    }

if (tempweekday2 == 0 || tempweekday2 == 6)
{

    if (i == day && month == cmonth) {
        padding += "<td class='weekends'  onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#00FF00\"; this.style.color=\"#FFFFFF\"' onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#F2F2F2\"; this.style.color=\"#F2F2F2\"'  ><div class='textarea-container2'>" + i + "<a href='http://www.ssic.com.my/e-system/e-driver/form.php?date="+totalParam+"' class='various' data-fancybox-type='iframe'><textarea readonly>click</textarea></div></td>";
    } 
    else {
        padding += "<td class='weekends' onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#F2F2F2\"' onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#F2F2F2\"'><div class='textarea-container4'>" + i + "<a href='http://www.ssic.com.my/e-system/e-driver/form.php?date="+totalParam+"' class='various' data-fancybox-type='iframe'><textarea readonly>click</textarea><div class='test'></div></div></td>";
    }
}
else
{
    if (i == day && month == cmonth) {
        padding += "<td bgcolor='#A9D1FA' class='currentday' onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#6699FF\"; this.style.color=\"#FFFFFF\"' onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#A9D1FA\"; this.style.color=\"#FFFFFF\"'><div class='textarea-container3'>" + i + "<a href='http://www.ssic.com.my/e-system/e-driver/form.php?date="+totalParam+"' class='various' data-fancybox-type='iframe'><textarea readonly>Today's Date</textarea></a></div></td>";
    } 
    else {
        padding += "<td bgcolor='#fff' class='currentmonth' onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#F2F2F2\"' onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#FFFFFF\"'><div class='textarea-container2'>" + i + "<a href='http://www.ssic.com.my/e-system/e-driver/form.php?date="+totalParam+"' class='various' data-fancybox-type='iframe'><textarea readonly>click here</textarea></a><div class='test'></div></div></td>";
    }
}
    tempweekday2++;
    i++;
}

var calendarTable = "<table class='calendar' bgcolor='E0E0DF'> <tr class='currentyear'><th class='blue' colspan='7'><?php echo"<a href='view.php?a=$previousM&year=$previousY' STYLE='TEXT-DECORATION: NONE'>&lt;&lt;</a>"; ?> " + monthNames[month] + " " + year + " <?php echo"<a href='view.php?a=$nextM&year=$nextY' STYLE='TEXT-DECORATION: NONE'>&gt;&gt;</a>"; ?></th></tr>";
calendarTable += "<tr class='weekdays'>  <th>Sun</th>  <th>Mon</th> <th>Tue</th> <th>Wed</th> <th>Thu</th> <th>Fri</th> <th>Sat</th> </tr>";
calendarTable += "<tr>";
calendarTable += padding;
calendarTable += "</tr></table>";
document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML += calendarTable;
}

function go12() {

for (i = <?php echo $i ?>; i < <?php echo $a ?>; i++) {
    calendar(i);
}
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
window.addEventListener('load', go12, false);
}   else if (window.attachEvent) {
window.attachEvent('onload', go12);
}
</script>
```

I'll appreciate any help or comment regarding with this issue. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest possibly using something someone else built than build it all yourself. They might have covered Use Cases you haven't built yet. [Mobile Calendar](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-mobile-event-calendar-with-dhtmlx--mobile-15849)

Comment: The thing is this is a web system application which every device can access via web browser. If I'm using the already built mobile calendar application, it can not be display on PC. Any ideas?

Comment: 1. Build a unique mobile website example m.site.com or mobile.site.com

2. Design existing website to adjust itself for various mobile devices (what is called “responsive design”) and use CSS3 Media Queries. Lastly, you can try to see if this plugin will help you. I don't know how detailed of a calendar you're wanting [Responsive JQuery Calendar](http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/)

Comment: I have tried to build a web application that does all that you've said, mobile, web etc and in the end, it was very hard to test on every browser on different devices and different versions of OSes and different versions of web browsers.

If I could do it over again, I would have picked 1, did some USER AGENT sniffing and sending them to a dedicated mobile or browser experience. Divide and Conquer it will make your life much easier.